# Dúvida vscode - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code

Eae pessoal, como criar um projeto ASP.NET, os tutoriais que procurei utilizam o New Project, mas não está aparecendo está opção, somente New File.

Comment: Tente dar uma olhada no comando dotnet new para criar um novo projeto via prompt de comando [Dotnet new](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore21)

Comment: Não seria New Folder?

Answer (score 1):

Está descrito na documentação oficial: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/setup-overview#_how-do-i-create-and-run-a-new-project

> VS Code doesn't include a traditional **File > New Project** dialog or pre-installed project templates. You'll need to add [additional components](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/additional-components) and scaffolders depending on your development interests. With scaffolding tools like [Yeoman](https://yeoman.io/) and the multitude of modules available through the npm package manager, you're sure to find appropriate templates and tools to create your projects.

Traduzindo...

*"O VS Code não inclui uma caixa de diálogo tradicional **File > New Project**  ou modelos de projeto pré-instalados. Você precisará adicionar componentes e scaffolders adicionais, dependendo dos seus interesses de desenvolvimento. Com ferramentas de scaffolding como o Yeoman e a multiplicidade de módulos disponíveis através do gerenciador de pacotes npm , você certamente encontrará modelos e ferramentas apropriados para criar seus projetos."*

**Em resumo** o VS Code não cria novos projetos (New Project), pois nativamente ele não tem "modelos de projetos" pré-instalados. Vc precisa instalar extensões para poder criar seus projetos, e o próprio VS Code sugere o https://yeoman.io/

*Aqui tem uma lista de extensões relacionadas a ASP.NET no marketplace do VS Code*
 https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=ASP.NET&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance